# D3.js - how selections work - Need clarification on Mike's article

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/, Mike talks about applying functions on selections.

> When you use a function to define a selection.attr or selection.style, the function is called for each element; the main difference with grouping is that the second argument to your function (i) is the within-group index rather than the within-selection index.

This might be simple, but for some reason, I can't completely understand this point. Would anyone be kind enough to explain this with an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the main difference with grouping is that the second argument to your
>   function (i) is the within-group index rather than the
>   within-selection index.

Remember the index passed in to any attr, style, etc. functions in d3?

```
...
.attr('something', function(d, index) {
     // major gymnastics with d and index
}
```

So when you do a selectAll, the index starts from 0 for **each** group.

So, if you do **two** chained selectAlls where the first (group) levels are rows (tr) and the second (child) levels are cells (td), you'd have the following passed in as indices for a 2 rows x 3 cells table

```
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
```

instead of

```
0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

which is what you'd expect when you select just 6 nodes with a **single** selectAll.

---

The following snippet of code illustrates this

```js
    d3.selectAll("#a tr").selectAll("td").text(function(d, index) {
      return index;
    })

     d3.selectAll("#b td").text(function(d, index) {
      return index;
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
Grouped cells (i.e. 2 selectAll)
<table id="a">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Ungrouped cells (i.e. 1 selectAll)
<table id="b">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

The first animation on the page you linked to (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) illustrates this pretty well - here's a marked up version of the same

[image]

Comment: It may be even clearer to consider this in the context of [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). I think this makes it quite intuitive why this is implemented in this way and the index isn't within selection.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - you're right. That explains "why you need it" in addition to the what it means + it has better diagrams that my MSPaint attempt :-)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: that helped a lot in understanding the "why" part.

Comment: @potatopeelings -  Thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation.